# why selecting objects one by one without replacement and selecting objects at the same time give same probability?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, intuition

I am trying to understand why the probability of selecting objects one by one without replacement is the same as selecting them at once. I see it algebraticaly thanks to the hypergeometric distribution. However ,i cannot  intuitively convince myself . I always feel that they must be different ,because when we draw objects one by one without replacement , it cause dependency , but when we draw them at once ,i.e selecting them at the same time , i feel that the dependency will be negated.

Briefly , i want a clear explanation (no algebraic ) about why selecting objects one by one without replacement and selecting objects at the same time give same probability ?

Intuative and clear clarifications will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

A simple example : We selects two employees for a job from a group of six people, of which one is female and five are male. Find the probability that the female is selected ?

First answer : $$\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{6}{2}}=1/3$$

Second answer: $$(1/6)(5/6)+(5/6)(1/6)=1/3$$

Comment: What does "give the same probability" mean?  Probability of what?

Comment: @lulu He's saying if you take $n$ balls out of the urn at once, you get the same distribution of outcomes as if you take $n$ of them out one at a time.

Comment: @lulu i meant they gives same result

Comment: @eyeballfrog yeap , you are right

Comment: The same result as what?  It obviously depends on what you are measuring.  If, say, you are trying to compute the expected number of times it takes to see the first red one, then you have to go one by one.

Comment: Sometimes order matters, and sometimes it doesn't.  It all depends on what variable(s) you are trying to observe.

Comment: @lulu i will write an example for you

Comment: I think what you are asking is going to end up being tautological. If you are measuring a variable $X$ which is independent of order then you can ignore the order.  Which, of course, is what "independent of order" means.

Comment: Post edit:  as I said, just a tautology.  Here, your variable, $X$ is $1$ if a female is present in the sample, $0$ otherwise.  That is independent of order so you can ignore the order.

Comment: @lulu can you explain what you meant by saying tautology ?secondly, can you provide some daily life examples like eyeballfrog's answers

Comment: Example of what?  Something where the order doesn't matter?  Sure, what's the probability that the roll of two dice sum to $8$.  What's the probability of being dealt $7$ or more spades in a bridge hand.  What's the probability that more people in a row have blood type $A$ than any other type?

Comment: *i want a clear explanation (no algebraic )* --- Maybe consider whether there is any difference between: (1) Someone selects the objects one at a time, and then when finished, gives all the objects to you at once; (2) Someone selects the objects all at once, and then when finished, gives the objects to you one at a time.

Comment: Things that do depend on order:  if you throw a pair of dice over and over will you get a $6$ and an $8$ before you get two $7's$.

Comment: My point, to stress:  dependence on order (or independence) is more a property of the variable you are observing than of the underlying population.

Comment: Small note: I think what you are looking for is an *intuitive* explanation," because some would consider an algebraic/combinatorial proof to be the clearest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I shuffle a deck of cards and deal you 5 cards, but you were looking away at the time and didn't see whether I took all 5 off the top at once or dealt 5 individually. Could this have possibly given you a different hand? No. So the two distributions must be the same.

For another example, suppose you have an urn full of numbered balls. The mouth of the urn has a detector, and each ball has an RFID chip corresponding to its number. I reach in and grab some balls. You see a readout of 4 balls that left the urn, in order but not timestamped. How could you tell if I grabbed 4 at once or removed 4 individually? After all, there's no way I can hold them so perfectly that they all passed the detector at the same time. They must have left the urn in some order. But that order would depend on the twist of my wrist as I remove them from the urn. How could that possibly affect the resulting distribution?

Comment: yes i want this type of answer , can you please provide some more examples

Comment: @randomuser Tried another one.